# Change MAIL_FROM_NAME value from laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-mail

I want to sent 2 mails, but from name is different for one, while for second its the default in env file

I tried this:

```
        Mail::send(
            'register.mail',
            ['record' => $record],
            function ($message) use ($record) {
                $message->to('usama@gmail.com');
                $message->subject('New Store Registration Request');
            }
        );
        // Update the mail from name
        Config::set('mail.from.name', 'Custom name');  
        Mail::send(
            'register.welcomeMail',
            ['record' => $record],
            function ($message) use ($record) {
                $message->to($record['email']);
                $message->subject('Store Registration');
                // Update the mail from name back to "Portal"
                Config::set('mail.from.name', 'Portal');
            }
        );
```

But this send mail with "Portal" as from name to both of these mails, am I doing it wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: there is `from`  method itself in the Message object so you can just do `$message->from(<address>, <name>);` I do not recommend this at all. Try to look into Laravel's Mailable it is a much clearer and better way to handle mail.

This thread will be helpful to you https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-change-from-address-on-mail-dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can change it without using the `config` or changing the `env` variables

Since you are using the a callback instead of a class you can just do this :

```
use Illuminate\Mail\Message;

Mail::send(
    view: 'register.email',
    data: ['record', $record],
    callback: function (Message $message) {
        $message->to('usama@gmail.com');
        $message->from('from@email.com', 'FromName');
        $message->subject('Mail Subject');
        
    }
);
```

The `$message` is a instance of `Message` class which where you can access the `from()` method to edit where the email come from. You can type hint it in the callback like the one I did so that you will be confuse.

You can also dig deeper to the `Mail::send()` to check how it works.